# check nulls using dqs

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-quality-services

I am new to SQL Server's Data Quality Services (`DQS`) feature.

I have a source table with few INT and string type column.

I need to implement a data quality rule in `DQS` using knowledge base domain to Identify the NULLS in the INT/String columns and convert that to Zero(0)/single space(' ').

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Looks like data quality services for SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877917.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This could be helpful: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16724.using-dqs-how-to-find-blankempty-values-in-your-data.aspx.  I've no experience with DQS, hence not posting as an answer.